# Nutch doesn't get UTF-8 characters

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, character-encoding, nutch

I crawl pages with **Nutch** and before indexing, I save the contents into separate files in the **Fetcher** class, so I don't use **-readseg** to get them back from indexed files. However, special characters such as "ü" and "ç" are saved as "?".

I did everything recommended in [Nutch Wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding). Edited the  tag's encoding attribute to UTF-8, it still doesn't work. I ran into some recommendations about making language changes in system files. I work in **Ubuntu 11.10**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 possibilities that I can think of:

1. Nutch works fine and your code writes things correctly to files but your environment (terminal/editor) is not displaying the characters properly on output console.
2. Your code for writing out the content (crawled by nutch) is not taking care of UTF-8 encoding.
3. Nutch not handling UTF-8 encoding correctly.

I had crawled pages, which had Chinese characters in it, with Nucth and I was able to see some garbage characters in the `readseg` output (this was with nutch 1.0). Later after I installed some language plugins and tweaked the settings in the terminal, I could see the characters. So, I think that #3 is not likely and you must focus on #1 and #2.

Comment: As I said, I don't use **-readseg**, I run **Nutch** in **Eclipse**. I opened a new project and copied my file saving code block and tried to save a string with special character and it succeeded. I think this rules out possibilities #1 and #2. **Eclipse**'s configured character encoding is UTF-8. I will focus on #3. You said "I installed some language packages", to what did you included them? Can you give some specific info on these plugins.

Comment: Another thing is, I tried to save an **.html** file from the browser which includes special characters. When I opened the saved file in gedit, I saw that special characters couldn't be saved but replaced with other characters such as "ý" for "ı" and "þ" for "ş".

Comment: I had installed Windows language support plugins and changed few settings on putty. (i dont use eclipse. i have a linux server and i connect to it from windows m/c via putty).

Comment: regarding yr code block for readng-writing special characters, did u try to print/display those characters on eclipse output / console ? Gedit could not display those characters becoz it might not have that support or its not enabled at yr m/c.

Comment: Same in Eclipse Console:

I get "G�R���MC�L�K TUTKUSU" instead of "GİRİŞİMCİLİK TUTKUSU".

Comment: i guess the sample code was not a part of nutch code and something which u wrote and yet u are not able to see the correct thing in the eclipse console. So dont you think that its possibility #1 or #2 ?

Comment: In the class **Fetcher** I get the variable **content** and write it to the file. Also, I debugged the project and the variable has �'s in it. I don't have anything done about the content other than writing it to the file.

Comment: check if eclipse is able to display characters correctly. i dont think it is. To do this, write small code to read and display a file with special characters. The test file should be one saved from browser and not nutch. Get this sorted out. If u dont see correct chars, get your eclipse special character problem resolved. If u see right thing displayed in eclipse console, then use a test file created from yr nutch content.

Comment: **Eclipse** couldn't write the special characters to console that I read from an HTML file. Thank you. Any suggestions for now?

Comment: The problem is in the **reader** not the **writer** by the way:

Comment: search on google to get Eclipse running with special characters. Verify if it works right with sample HTML file. Once done, then verify nutch behavior.

Comment: As a help to people work in Nutch, the problem can be solved by converting the byte array returned from **content.getContent()** to **String** with an encoding selection:

String myContent = new String(content.getContent(), myEncoding);

To find the encoding, just take the substring of the content with the index of **charset**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that i've solved encoding problem. See the code below:

```
co = true;
fe = true;
ge = true;
pa = true;
pd = true;
pt = true;
SegmentReader segmentReader2 = new SegmentReader(crwlNutchCommon.nutch_conf, co, fe, ge, pa, pd, pt);
HashMap<String, List<Writable>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<Writable>>();
segmentReader2.get(path, new Text("some_url"),
```

new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("somefile1"), "UTF-8"),hm);

The file somefile1 will probably have wrong encoding, but go further:

```
FileOutputStream fos; 
DataOutputStream dos;
File file= new File("somefile2");
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);
hm.get("co").get(0).write(dos); // look
```

And that's working! somefile2 will be "raw", without any encoding modification, but with some extra data in the beginning and after the ending - I think it will be possible to parse them analyzing "Content.java" source file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already got the solution. Nutch was getting UTF-8 characters right. What I've done, is to convert the **content** variable in **Fetcher** class to string with encoding that I retrieved from the content itself.

Answer (score 0):

Following you I decided to modify Fetcher class and added support to save content directly to mysql database. It works much better and faster.